# How to reply to messages in discord with python requests?

Tags: python, discord, request

I need to reply to the message. But my code prints this: `{"code": 50035, "errors": {"message_reference": {"_errors": [{"code": "MODEL_TYPE_CONVERT", "message": "Only dictionaries may be used in a ModelType"}]}}, "message": "Invalid Form Body"}`

```
import requests
url = "https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/{}/messages".format(channel_id)
data = {"content": "oof",'message_reference': {'channel_id': channel_id, 'message_id': message_id}}
header = {"authorization": token}
r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=header)
print(r.text)
```

And I definitely don't want to use discord.py

Comment: do you have link to documentation for this function?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is right, but you have to use **json** parameter instead of **data** parameter

`r = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=header)`